# Mathematica - Separate elements of a string into columns?

Tags: string, list, wolfram-mathematica

I'm producing encoded output that is a list of strings that look like lists. Is there a way to turn them into actual lists so I can select elements and format them into columns? Or a way to select characters in the strings and put those in columns?

```
  Button[
    "Run",
    {afit = Input["Please Enter ID#", deleteme] ;
    ClearAll[dat],
    dat := TraumaEncoding@afit;
    ClearAll[funcel],
    funcel[p_String] :=
     Which[StringMatchQ[
      p, ("*no new ones*" | "*no new marks*" | 
      "*old wounds healing*"), 
      IgnoreCase -> True], "0",
      StringMatchQ[p, ("*abrasion*"), IgnoreCase -> True], "{1,0}",
      StringMatchQ[p, ("*lacer*"), IgnoreCase -> True], "{1,1}",
      StringMatchQ[p, ("*punct*") | ("*pct*"), 
      IgnoreCase -> True], "{1,2}",
      StringMatchQ[p, ("*amput*"), IgnoreCase -> True], "{1,4}",
      StringMatchQ[
       p, ("*wound*" | "*injur*" | "*trauma*" | 
       "*swollen*" | "*swell*"), IgnoreCase -> True], 1, True, 0];
    funcel[___] := 0;
    ClearAll[func],
    func[l_List] := 
     Which[MemberQ[Map[funcel, l], "0"], "0", 
      MemberQ[Map[funcel, l], "{1,4}"], "{1,4}", 
      MemberQ[Map[funcel, l], "{1,2}"], "{1,2}", 
      MemberQ[Map[funcel, l], "{1,1}"], "{1,1}", 
      MemberQ[Map[funcel, l], "1-0"], "1,0", MemberQ[Map[funcel, l], 1],
       1, True, 0];
    listo := Map[func, dat]},
  Background -> Yellow, Sequence @@ $ButtonOptions
  ]
```

Produces something like this:

```
   {"{1,2}", "{1,2}", "0", "{1,2}", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"}
```

I need to turn that into something more like this, ideally that I can export into an Excel file:

```
    Header  Header
      1       2
      1       2
      0
      1       2
      0
     etc.,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ToExpression["{1,2}"]

==> {1,2}
```

or the whole list:

```
data =
 Prepend[ToExpression /@ {"{1,2}", "{1,2}", "0", "{1,2}", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0"}, {"header1", "header2"}]

(* ==> {{"header1", "header2"}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}, 0, {1 2}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}   *)
```

Formatted as a table:

[image]

To export:

```
Export["filename.csv", data]
```

Comment: THANK YOU :D I'll test it really quick and then select your answer!

Comment: Hm... it's not exporting right. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: Do you export to xls  or csv? xls has problems with the fact that your table is not a rectangular list of lists. CSV works better there. If you want to use take care the table is rectangular using PadRight (and make the "0" output a list, preferably {"0","0"}) . BTW why not let your function output the list directly. Why would you need strings at all?

Answer (score 2):

One minor note: you actually don't need to `Map` `ToExpression` to the list, instead, you can `Apply` it

```
In[91]:= ToExpression@{"{1,2}","{1,2}","0","{1,2}","0","0","0","0","0"}
Out[91]= {{1,2},{1,2},0,{1,2},0,0,0,0,0}
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you :D I imagine that's a little faster.

Comment: It exports all right for me:

 In[92]:= data=ToExpression@{"{1,2}","{1,2}","0","{1,2}","0","0","0","0","0"}
 Out[92]= {{1,2},{1,2},0,{1,2},0,0,0,0,0}
 In[94]:= file=ToFileName[{$TemporaryDirectory},"filename.csv"]
 Out[94]= /tmp/filename.csv
 In[95]:= Export[file,data]
 Out[95]= /tmp/filename.csv
 In[96]:= FilePrint[file]
 During evaluation of In[96]:=
 1,2
 1,2
 0
 1,2
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0